# Trend DeepSecurityManager - API for Scheduled Task Failing in v11.1.227

Tags: deepsecurity

I'm trying to create some scheduled tasks via the API but I keep getting a 404 error with the following message:

```
"RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: https://localhost/v1/api/scheduledtasks"
```

Here's what my api call looks like:

```
curl -k -X GET https://localhost:443/api/scheduledtasks -H 'api-secret-key: redacted' -H 'api-version: v1'
```

I'm able to list out other configurations like policies and system settings using the api so I don't think it is an authentication problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The scheduled task endpoint is not available in Deep Security 11.1.   You can upgrade your manager to version 11.2.225 to use that endpoint. (I work at Trend Micro as a CSE)

Here is an example cURL request using version 11.2.225:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://localhost:80/api/scheduledtasks \
  -H 'api-secret-key: redacted' \
  -H 'api-version: v1' --insecure
```

Response:

```
{
  "scheduledTasks": [{
    "name": "Component Update Task",
    "type": "check-for-security-updates",
    "scheduleDetails": {
      "timeZone": "America/Bahia_Banderas",
      "recurrenceType": "daily",
      "dailyScheduleParameters": {
        "startTime": 1535477100000,
        "frequencyType": "everyday"
      }
    },
    "enabled": true,
    "lastRunTime": 1542651954042,
    "nextRunTime": 1542738300000,
    "checkForSecurityUpdatesTaskParameters": {
      "computerFilter": {
        "type": "all-computers"
      }
    },
    "ID": 1
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!